# Configuración de WebLogic no encuentra la carpeta JDBC

Tags: configuración, weblogic

> WebLogic.application.ModuleException: Java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:(ruta)\jdbc no se encuentra la carpeta

Me podrían indicar cómo generarla

### Intentos

Tengo una versión anterior del `wls10.3.4` recuerdo que en un momento realice una réplica y la configuración fue desde la IP/consolé me mandó al administrador de WebLogic y por eso me generó la `jdbc`

En este caso no me permite acceder de la misma forma, también intenté eliminar los archivos de `config.xml` relacionados a `jdbc` pero no me funcionó, copié una carpeta de `jdbc` del WebLogic 10.3.4 pero me mandó que faltaban algunos otros archivos

Answer (score 0):

si se presenta una situación como la mencionada es necesario tener el dominio complete ya que la configuración crea las carpetas y las rutas, en mi caso para darle solución tuve que realizar la configuración desde 0.

Si deseas pasar el dominio a un tercero debes indicarle que debe

1. agregar un su ip en el archivo de configuración
2. validar las rutas en el archivo de arranque
3. validar los archivos de configuración de server
4. así como en la carpeta de Oracle contar con tus jar para la conexión de arranque

Comment: entiendo que lo que hiciste fue desde el administrador agregar el jar de tu base de datos para resolver el problema

Comment: En mi caso hice la configuración desde 0, genere scripts bash que ingresé en consola para automatizar el proceso de creación de dominio, ya que no contaba con el Jar pero si se cuenta con este se soluciona el inconveniente, en mi caso no vi como generarlo con el dominio ya creado

Comment: Entiendo. Te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta y así obtendrás tus primeros puntos de reputación en el sitio.